# RegisterStartupScript not registering scripts with nested masterpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

```
void RegisterScript()
 {
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "someScript", "alert('I was called from master page!')", true);
}
```

The above method is called form page_load event of masterpage (Assume `Site.master`).

Above method registers a script on the contentpage when the contentpage directly inherits the masterpage,

but no script is registered when masterpage is nested.

i.e the contentpage inherits a masterpage (assume `view.master`) and this masterpage (`view.master`) inherits the original masterpage (`Site.master`)

I have already tried   `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` and `this.registerclientScriptBlock()` ... how to solve this?

Comment: any help on this please!!